# Error on clicking on Text to Speech tab in Speech properties in Control Panel

Tags: windows-xp, control-panel, text-to-speech

When I click on Text to Speech tab in Speech properties I receive error:

"C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Speech\sapi.cpl",Speech".

There's a hotfix mentioned the the KBs in MS support.For that MS sent me a password protected file ; 170483_ENU_i386_zip.exe which contained two files : WindowsXP-KB838659-x86-ENU.EXE and
WINDOWSXP-KB838659-X86-ENU-Symbols.EXE . The first one did not install as it said i already had it and the second one unpacked some dlls which i don't know how to use.

I also tried Re-registering sapi.dll on Windows XP using
C:\Windows\System32\regsvr32.exe

Is there any other fix to this error?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the problem I've had for years and got nowhere with the info on Microsoft or the web until today. I found the [brilliant but simple answer](http://www.mcse.ms/message1542278.html) to fix this stubborn problem.

I recommend you check it out. I hope it works for you too. Good luck!